# Javaclick Runs before button is clicked

Tags: javascript

When I open the page the javascript runs before the button is clicked. It also runs when I do click the button. I don't want it to run until I click the button.

Code:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 45.973, lng: -68.81},
    zoom: 10
  });
}
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#map {
 height: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button id="showLocation" onclick="initMap()">Show Location</button>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDTUe6NaV7fwxOOESwnEdq3YcT9Y2Wr8lg&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

You are passing `initMap` as a callback to 'api/js'. This means that when the script loads it will run the callback method, i.e. execute `initMap`.

Try removing `&callback=initMap` from the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your *initMap()* to some other name. Google Maps API is calling this function name upon init on the callback.

Answer (score 2):

Remove "&callback=initMap" from the script-src-tag on the last line.